# Prove by Mathematical Induction that $3^n > n^2 + 4$ for $n\geq 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I end up getting this as the last step:
$3^{k+1} > (k+1)^2 + 4$

$3^k * 3 > (k^2 + 4) + 2k + 1$

and here is where I get stuck.

Comment: Hi mark welcome to MSE! Can you please edit the equations better using Mathjax?

Comment: sure! let me add more details as well

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to prove that $3^{n} >n^{2}+4$ note that this is true for $n=2$. If it holds for some $n$ then $3^{n+1} =3(3^{n}) >3(n^{2}+4)$. We have to show that $3n^{2}+12 >(n+1)^{2}+4$ or $2n^{2}-2n+7>0$. write LHS as $2(n-\frac  1 2)^{2}+(7-\frac 1  2)$ which is clearly positive.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem, if $n\ge 3$ then
$$
3^n=(2+1)^n
= 2^n + n2^{n-1} + n(n-1)2^{n-3} + \cdots
\ge 2^n + 2^{n - 3} (n^2 + 3 n)
\ge 2^n + 2^{n - 3} n^2
\ge 4 + n^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have done the half of the proof you need just to show that :
$$3^{n+1}>(n+1)^2+4$$
By the induction hypothesis you have :
$$3^n>n^2+4$$
Thus :
\begin{align} 
3^n\times 3&>3(n^2+4) \\\
3^{n+1}&>3n^2+12
\end{align}
Now we need to show that :
$$3n^2+12>(n+1)^2+4$$
The best way to do this is by the difference :

\begin{align} 
3n^2+12-\bigg((n+1)^2+4\bigg)&=3n^2+12-n^2-2n-5 \\\
&=2n^2-2n+7\\\ 
&=n(2n-2)+7
\end{align}
Since $n \ge 2$ thus :
\begin{align}
2n &\ge 4 \\\
2n-2 &\ge 2 \\\
n(2n-2)& \ge 4
\end{align}
Finally $n(2n-2)+7$ is positive :
Therefore :
$$3n^2+12>(n+1)^2+4$$
And :
$$3^{n+1}>(n+1)^2+4$$
Hence by induction we have shown that :
$$3^n>n^2+4$$
is a true property for all $n\ge 2$.

I hope that my answer is clear, Good luck !